# need to auto-scale repeating background image

Tags: css, background-image

I have a 1px wide background image that repeats over the x coordinate for a div that's size can be adjusted. horizontally. I want that background image to stretch or shrink automatically. How can I achieve this in all major browsers including IE7+?

Answer (score 0):

You know what's awesome? We don't need to use gradient images any more. Here's a link to a handy-dandy gradient tool that works for all major browsers, including support for IE6, 7, 8 & 9

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: it's more than that. is a special image, not a gradient.

Comment: Jeez, you didn't have to knock me down a point. having a 1px image that stretches 100%... yeah, I assumed but I've never seen anyone use something like that for anything else. So before I make any other assumptions, you want this to stretch how exactly? 100% vertically?

Comment: This can't be done with pure css. You will need to do it in javascript or find another alternative to stretching it (ie making the image way taller than it needs to be.) I'm curious, though, what image would you want stretched vertically? I can't imagine what this would be used for.